# How to Extract Data from OTM into SQL Server using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, obiee

I am trying to fetch data from OTM(Oracle Transport Management) into SQL Server. SO just wanted to know is it possible to extract data from otm into SQL Server using SSIS. We are presently using FTI and OBIEE(BICS) and then fetching that data into SQL Server.

Any suitable idea or methods will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming OTM has an Oracle database backend, then you can use SSIS to extract data from it. You can connect to Oracle with SSIS using an Oracle OLE DB driver or the Attunity driver.